# How to remove drill down and normal hyperlinks in Excel version of reports?

Tags: reporting-services

Suppose a report is rendered on the Report Server when a user saves it in Excel format.
The user then opens the report. All hyperlinks and drill down in the report are available in Excel, but if user clicks on it, it opens the result in a web browser.

How to restrict these hyperlinks while exporting to Excel from report Server?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an expression in the ACTION  - GO TO REPORT option 
=IIf(Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive, "Your Report", Nothing)
this will remove the hyperlinks for Excel and PDF exports